# what is the compatible titanium appcelerator simulator for samsung galaxy s2 for the development?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, android-virtual-device

I am developing an iphone/ android application using titanium accelerator I need to test this app for the samsung galaxy s2 devices. So what simulator should I use for testing?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an AVD [Android Virtual Device] or use a real Samsung device.

To create an AVD you can find a how-to video here [Samsung Galaxy S2 AVD](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4ixHNotk_4)